# What's the negation of "Sooner or later"?

Tags: phrases, negation

I find the following sentence in need for the "Sooner or later" but in its negative form.

The sentence:

> This is what I don't intend in disclosing. **Not sooner or later.**

The speaker wants to emphasize on his refusal of disclosing an X matter. I don't find "Sooner or later" fits the sentence, with preserving the speaker's technique of stating that.

But it may fit if the structure of the sentence changed a bit, like:

> This is what I don't intend in disclosing **sooner or later**.

According to Collins Dictionary:

> If you say that something will happen sooner or later, you mean that it **will happen** at some time in the future, even though it might take a long time.
>
> *Sooner or later she would be caught by the police.*

In my case, the speaker is certain that that **won't happen** in the future. So, is there a negative form of the phrase? Since I didn't find it stated on the Internet in its negation. [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?ei=Osr1XJK8H87VwQL2m6DIAQ&q=not+sooner+or+later&oq=not+sooner+or+later&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i30l2j0i7i5i30j0i8i30.106901.107286..108799...0.0..0.176.648.0j4......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i7i30j0i8i7i30.TfYG6Sk0iEo) - [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=not+sooner+or+later&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjkiPLc187iAhVDLFAKHVvkCQgQ_AUIFSgA&biw=1496&bih=762)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an antonym for "sooner or later" in this context, you can use "never" or "not ever." Alternatively, you can rephrase with "don't ever."

• This is what I never intend on disclosing.

• This is what I don't ever intend on disclosing.

• This is what I don't intend on disclosing. Ever.

• This is what I don't intend on disclosing. Never.

• This is what I don't intend on disclosing. Not ever.

These five examples are essentially identical in meaning, but to me each is a bit more emphatic than the one before. Also, note that while the third and fourth examples might look like they have opposite meanings (since they are identical but for the fact that one uses "ever" and the other uses "never"), in fact they are equivalent.

Finally, although this isn't what you're asking about, please note that we usually say "intend on," not "intend in." However, in each of the above examples, I would actually be inclined to use "intend to disclose" rather than "intend on disclosing." "Intend on disclosing" isn't exactly wrong, but it feels less natural to me.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions and for pointing out my other mistakes (misusages).

Comment: Further to Nanigashi’s Answer, much of the problem was in reading "sooner or later" as meaning anything but “sometime”, presumably because it seems to include at two words with different meanings. In fact, what’s needed is to simply it to its true meaning: “sometime” which makes “never” much obviously the negative form.

By the way, “negation” is a process. “Negative” was needed here. 

Further, “intend on” would normally be understood but the correct options are only “I intend to” or “I am intent on” or  

Check out Cookie Bear's contribution: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZZnr0kV4www